# easter_date php calculation one day short in server

Tags: php, date

hi Im using code that gets the holiday of month and year, this function is relying on easter_date internal php code to calcuate the exacter date of easter date.
The issue is the function works in  localhost and the following code gives the right easter western date '2016-03-27' :

```
echo date('Y-m-d',easter_date($year));
```

but in the server it's short by one day, i don't know why.The same function it returns to me '2016-03-26'

Im using cakephp.
Thanks in advance

Comment: And the timezone of your server? Because easter_date() returns a timestamp, which will be adjusted when you use date() based on your timezone settings

Comment: i got in cakephp this code date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); and in my server my timezone is Europe/paris

Comment: if even i changed the timezone in my local machine nothing changes, it gives the right easter date

Comment: Take a look at the first note in PHP doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.easter-date.php  This might be the issue you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking in the php documentation i've found this function that i used and it worked perfectely instead of the default easter_date function :

```
public static function get_easter_datetime($year) {
        $base = new DateTime("$year-03-21");
        $days = easter_days($year);

        return $base->add(new DateInterval("P{$days}D"));
    }
```

and instead of `$date_easter=easter_date()` i user the new created function like this :

```
$easterDate  = static::get_easter_datetime($year)->getTimestamp();
```